# php function arguments with a variable

Tags: php, function, global-variables, arguments

Is there a way to set up default function arguments with variables in them such as

```
function example($test = 'abc', $image = $scripturl . 'abc.png')
{
        // ...
}
```

The reason I want to do this is because I have sources that I have global variable settings with the path set up so that it is easy to grab when I need to include a css file or image.

The code above gives an unexpected T_VARIABLE...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not possible; default arguments must be constant.

You can easily emulate it like this though:

```
function example($test = 'abc', $image = null) {
    if($image === null) {
        global $scripturl;
        $image = $scripturl . 'abc.png';
    }
}
```

Comment: some OOP may be useful. Make $scripturl an object variable set upon construction, then it could be $this->scripturl.

Comment: Ye, I guess this would be the only solution and to use it in the function :/ - Thanks for the reply!

Comment: don't forget `global $scripturl;` for external variables that aren't superglobals

Answer (score 4):

Default values should be a constant. They should have the value, that is already available in compile time, not in a runtime.

Comment: What I am proposing would be constant at compile since those settings would only change if the sources moved. I get your point but is there any way to do something the way I am proposing? I can always add in the variable in the function though... I think I will go with @ThiefMaster solution

Answer (score 1):

No. Default values in function arguments must be constant values, not the results of expressions: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default

At the point the arguments are parsed, $scripturl will not exist anyways, and would always come out as NULL, since you couldn't make it global before it's used.

Answer (score 1):

well, as the error already stated, you cannot use a variable as (part of) default value in function signature.

what you can do however, is pass some known illegal value (`null` for instance) and then check inside the function and assign if needed:

```
function example($test = 'abc', $image = null)
{
   global $scripturl;
   if($image === null) $image = $scripturl . 'abc.png';
   ...
}
```